# Combining series to create a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I have two series of stock prices (containing date, ticker, open, high, low, close) and I'd like to know how to combine them to create a dataframe just like the way Yahoo!Finance does. Is it possible?

"Join and merge" don't seem to work

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.concat([sr1, sr2], axis=1)` if neither one of `join` and `merge` work.